# ObjectUnsubscribedError when trying to prevent subscribing twice

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a Service and a component that uses it:

- `PagesService`
- `PagesListComponent`

In the `PagesService` I have an array of `Pages`. I notify changes in the array via a `BehaviorSubject` which both of them are subscribed to.

The `PagesService` are provided at `bootstrap`, to have just one instance shared. That's because I need to keep the array, instead of downloading the pages everytime they are needed.

The code is the following:

**pages.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Page } from './../models/page';

@Injectable() export class PagesService {

    public pages$: BehaviorSubject<Page[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Page[]>([]);
    private pages: Page[] = [];

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getPagesListener() {
        return this.pages$;
    }
    getAll() {
        this.http.get('/mockups/pages.json').map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
            res => { this.resetPagesFromJson(res); },
            err => { console.log('Pages could not be fetched'); }
        );
    }

    private resetPagesFromJson(pagesArr: Array<any>) {
        // Parses de Array<any> and creates an Array<Page>
        this.pages$.next(this.pages);
    }
}
```

**pages_list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { PagesService } from '../../shared/services/pages.service';
import { GoPage } from '../../shared/models/page';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'go-pages-list',
    templateUrl: 'pages_list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['pages_list.component.css']
})
export class PagesListComponent implements OnInit {
    pages$: BehaviorSubject<GoPage[]>;
    pages: GoPage[];
    constructor(private pagesService: PagesService, private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.pages$ = this.pagesService.getPagesListener();
        this.pages$.subscribe((pages) => { this.pages = pages; console.log(pages) });
        this.pagesService.getAll();
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.pages$.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

This works fine the first time, both the subscription onInit and de unsubscription onDestroy. But when I return to the list and try to subscribe again (to fetch the current value of pages[] and listen for future changes), it **fires the error** `EXCEPTION: ObjectUnsubscribedError`.

If I don't unsubscribe, everytime I enter to the list, a new subscription is stacked, and all of them are fired when a next() is received.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

I would get the subscription and unsubscribe on it this way and not on the subject directly:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.pages$ = this.pagesService.getPagesListener();
  this.subscription = this.pages$.subscribe((pages) => { // <-------
    this.pages = pages; console.log(pages);
  });
  this.pagesService.getAll();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe(); // <-------
}
```

Comment: can you mention why did directly calling unsubscribe on the injected subject reference didn't work ?

Comment: "The unsubscribe method in the Subject class doesn’t actually unsubscribe anything. Instead, it marks the subject as closed and sets its internal array subscribed observers  to null" More in detail: https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-closed-subjects-1b6f76c1b63c

Comment: i've just tried on an eventEmitter that i need to unsubscribe and re subscribe and it works perfectly... but i still have a question: why this.subscription can be unsubscribed and re subscribed without problems meanwhile if you do it directly to the event/observable cannot be re subscribed?

Comment: Conclusion: Save subscription in VARIABLE, and call unsubscribe method on it (not on function that you are subscribed to)! Man thank you a lot!

Answer (score 28):

.subscribe() returns a Subscription

- You should use this to unsubscribe

e.g. 
Parent has a reloadSubject: Subject;

- child1 -> subscribes
- child2 -> subscribes

child1 - "WORKS" -> unsubscribe's his subscription

```
ngOnInit{ 
  sub: Subscription = parent.subscribe();
}
onDestroy{
  this.sub.unsubscribe();
}
```

child2 - "DOES NOT WORK" -> unsubscribe's the whole parent

```
ngOnInit{ 
  parent.subscribe();
}

onDestroy{
  parent.unsubscribe();
}
```

If you call unsubscribe on the parent both children are gone.

If you unsubscribe the Subscription that you get from the .subscribe()
then only one child is unsubscribed.

Please correct me if I am wrong!