# ObjectUnsuscribedError when navigating to other components - Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-subscriptions

Hello I'm currently facing a problem with subscriptions when I navigate to another component of the app.
The way I handle the subscriptions is on an array.

```
private _subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
```

and every time I have to subscribe, I push the subscription to this array.

```
this._subscriptions.push(
  this._headerService.rightIconClicked
    .subscribe(() => this._logout())
);
```

on my ngOnDestroy method, I loop through this array and unsubscribe from every subscription.

```
if (this._subscriptions) {
  this._subscriptions.forEach((sub: Subscription) => {
    sub.unsubscribe();
  });
}
```

To navigate, I'm using `navigate()` method from angular router.

```
private _logout() {
  this._router.navigate(['/login'])
}
```

And the error I get is the following:
[image]

Something to take in account is that on my ngOnDestroy() method, before unsubscribing, I have a console.log() to show that I'm there. And that is not even displayed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure can this help you. But please if possible can you try an add a condition `if(!sub.closed) {  sub.unsubscribe(); }`

Comment: hello.. Nope, it didn't work..

Comment: can you check this question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081878/objectunsubscribederror-when-trying-to-prevent-subscribing-twice